# pysimplesoap web service return connection refused

Tags: python, soap, pysimplesoap

I've created some web services using **pysimplesoap** like on this documentation:

https://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/wiki/SoapServer

When I tested it, I called it like this:

```
from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy
from SOAPpy import Types

namespace = "http://localhost:8008"
url = "http://localhost:8008"

proxy = SOAPProxy(url, namespace)

response = proxy.dummy(times=5, name="test")
print response
```

And it worked for all of my web services, but when I try to call it by using an library which is needed to specify the WSDL, it returns "Could not connect to host".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I used the object **".wsdl()"** to generate the correct WSDL and saved it into a file, the WSDL generated by default wasn't correct, was missing variable types and the correct server address...

Answer (score 0):

The server name `localhost` is only meaningful on your computer. Once outside, other computers won't be able to see it.

1) find out your external IP, with http://www.whatismyip.com/ or another service. Note that IPs change over time.

2) plug the IP in to http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html

If your local service is answering IP requests as well as from localhost, you're done!